# What would be the technical difficulties running WebRTC without a server?

Tags: webrtc

WebRTC, after all, is a peer-to-peer technology and thus having a server like Janus, Jitsi, Red5, etc defeats the purpose of being p2p. **What would be the technical difficulties running WebRTC without such a server?**

I mean at least to run WebRTC with just a basic backend, like a BaaS, Firebase, or similar as the only "server" component in the infrastructure.

Comment: If you want to record the stream, or for example, stream it to youtube or some livestream channel trough RTP, just the basic WebRTC will not work. A large number of peers would be a problem too, with a server you can merge it in one single stream.

Comment: * Don't forget of the signaling server.

Comment: Yes, this is for a video conferencing setup. Do you mean it's not possible just to use Firebase as a signaling server and not have those Janus, Jitsi nor Red5 at all?

Comment: It's possible to use just the signaling server and avoid media servers. Although as I said, for large number of peers or other functionalities like recording you'd go better with a media server.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to build simple conferencing with just a signaling server! There are a few advantages to having a media server. This isn't exhaustive, but the things that have mattered for me in production.

#### Less resource usage for users

If you do mesh signaling every user connect with each other via P2P. This means if you have a 4 person conference call everyone needs to upload their video 3 times. If you have a media server each user uploads only once, and then the server distributes the video. This means a lot less CPU and network usage for each user.

#### P2P Connections reveal details about the user

If users are connecting directly to each other they are able to figure out details like their public IP. If you route everything through a server you can anonymize more things.

#### Less variability to deal with

When doing P2P connections you will deal with a lot more variables. It will be harder to figure out which user's internet is causing issue, or debug encode/decode issues. A few times running a SFU has come really in handy because I was able to debug something that would have been impossible when just doing P2P.

Comment: Isn't the setup just one time and effectively everyone ins the channel gets the stream via P2P

Comment: Yes, but if you are doing P2P that means you need to upload it directly to each viewer. If you do a media server everyone connects to the media server. https://medium.com/@khan_honney/webrtc-servers-and-multi-party-communication-in-webrtc-6bf3870b15eb is a helpful resource.